# Count character groups in string with semi colons

Tags: sql, string, sapb1

Had a bit of a search but couldnt find an answer to this problem. String manipulation is not my strong suit.

I have the following example string.

`7849;7985;8044;8253;8254;16733`

I need to count the number of 'Ids' in the string. Using the above example it should come out as 6 because each set of numbers between the semi colon represents one ID.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of semicolons using string functions and then add one:

```
select (length(str) - length(replace(str, ';', '')) + 1 as num_elements
```

That said, you should fix your data model so you are not storing multiple values in a string.  These should be on separate rows of another table.

If you are not using MySQL, some databases use `LEN()` instead of `LENGTH()`.

Comment: Thanks for response Gordon, its not working though. It does alright up to 4 but any that are 6 or greater it just stops at 7, using the following.

7809;7850;7890;7917;7938;7986;8045;8072;15149 - This only gives 7. Using the following code

len(CAST(A.U_AceqCodes AS VARCHAR)) - len(replace(CAST(A.U_AceqCodes AS VARCHAR), ';', '')) + 1

Unfortunately the data is coming from an addon within SAP B1 and I dont have control of the data model.

Comment: @NickJones . . . (1) That is not the code in this answer.  (2) That is not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: Using your code above I get The replace function requires 3 arguments

Comment: All working now, the problem was when I was casting the field to varchar i didnt include MAX so it was limiting it.